# x509 certificate not recognized in Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I got one Digital certificate from NeutralUS CA. I have installed in my local system. I found the installed certificate under Personal Certificates in MMC and my application validated with this certificate. I just moved to my application to our production server and installed same certificate. here also i can see my certificate under personal certificates in MMC on windows server 2008 R2. But when I am trying to load certificate with serial number, it is showing the store certificates count is zero. Could you please tell me what would be the reason? Why it is not recognize from the Personal folder. i have only one certificate in in personal folder.

```
var clientCertStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

clientCertStore.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly & OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
base.Data.ErrorLog.Append("Certificates Count : " + clientCertStore.Certificates.Count);
```

I just log the data into one text file... it is giving `clientCertStore.Certificates.Count` as 0.

Comment: coud it happen your certificate got installed on StoreLocation.LocalMachine?

Comment: The code you pasted must run under a proper user account, so as to query the personal store of that user. Otherwise, it reads a completely different place and can possibly return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> I got one Digital certificate from NeutralUS CA. I have installed in my local system.

What is installed? Is the end entity cert installed and trusted? Or is it the NeutralUS CA?

I could not find the NeutralUS CA for download on the net. That's unusual.

---

> Could you please tell me what would be the reason? Why it is not recognize from the Personal folder.

I suspect its a problem with accounts (but its just a guess). What account was the certificate installed under, and what account is the program running under?

---

I really despise how difficult Java and .Net make it to use a damn certificate. Here's the code I use to avoid wasting time with those damn stores. It allows you to load directly from the filesystem or an app bundle. It also *does not* use the hundreds of CAs and subordinates that Windows carries around.

```
static bool VerifyServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    try
    {
        String CA_FILE = "ca-cert.der";
        X509Certificate2 ca = new X509Certificate2();
        ca.Import(CA_FILE);

        X509Chain chain2 = new X509Chain();
        chain2.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(ca);

        // Check all properties
        chain2.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

        // This setup does not have revocation information
        chain2.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

        // Are there any failures from building the chain?
        chain2.Build(new X509Certificate2(certificate));
        if (chain2.ChainStatus.Length == 0)
            return true;

        // Verify the status is NoError
        bool result = chain2.ChainStatus[0].Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError;
        Debug.Assert(result == true);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    return false;
}
```

And I still have not figured out how to set the original `X509Chain chain` that comes in as a parameter to the `X509Chain chain2` that I want to use *before* the callback `VerifyServerCertificate` is invoked.